# how to display image dynamically in listview android?

Tags: android, image, listview

( i have image in res/drawable, the name of image in database)
I've done to display image from res/drawable to listview, but images appear same picture..
i want display difference image from the others....

how to change image id from drawable folder (using setImageResource()). My drawable folder contains more than 1 image and i want to change these images using name in database already stored..

here is my code from tutorial...

> //the result from database (image2.jpg)

```
public KontakItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<KontakItemDetails> results) {
    itemDetailsrrayList = results;
    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try{
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.kontak_details_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
        holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemDescription());


    holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.iddy);

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Error("kontakitemlistadapter :"+ex.toString());

    }
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_itemName;
    TextView txt_itemDescription;
    TextView txt_itemPrice;
    ImageView itemImage;
}
```

i think my problem is here..

> > holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.iddy);

how to change R.drawable.iddy to be path name??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all Drawables id's in an Arrays as :

```
private Integer[] images;

Field[] list = R.drawable.class.getFields();
int count = 0, index = 0, j = list.length;

images = new Integer[count];
try {
   for(int i=0; i < j; i++)
    images[index++] = list[i].getInt(null);
 } catch(Exception e) {}
```

now use images Array for setting Image src in getView method of Adapter as:

```
holder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
```

Comment: you can also see [this](http://cdn-local.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/5/src5-dan/Intents08/src/net/cs76/lectures/intents08/ImageAdapter.java) example

Comment: ok.thanks...where i can place result of name from database if the name of image have unique name each other....ex: "image_komputer.jpg","img_mouse.jpg" not "image1.jpg","image2.jpg" ??

Comment: @ltvie : means you have images names in db as "image_komputer.jpg","img_mouse.jpg"....?

Comment: yes,,,images names that i stored in db..images file i save in res/drawable...i want load images to listview based images name in db *sorry for my bad english..

Comment: @ltvie : i have alreay share a link with you you can see [this](http://cdn-local.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/5/src5-dan/Intents08/src/net/cs76/lectures/intents08/ImageAdapter.java) example . in this example he is selecting only images from drawable with names `img_` . i same way you can change your code by placing a condition inside for loop . and get image which only contains `image_`. you have any issue in implementing this ?

Comment: @ltvie :Glad I could help. if this answer help u then ,mark it as answer.

Comment: "mark it as answer"..i'm newbie here..where i can find link/button "answered" ??:D

Comment: @ltvie : i think you have already accepted two question's answer by click on Right sign on top of answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the drawable reference based on the context

```
holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.iddy);
```